# IP-based country code appended dynamically in option box?

Tags: jquery

I need help in document loading time. IP country code, selected in my country selectbox field.

I tried this function, but it is not working.

```
                 var code =geoip_country_code();

    //$('#selectCountry').attr('for');
    //alert($('#selectCountry').val());


    $(function()
    {
        $('#selectCountry option:selected').attr('for',code);

        $('#selectCountry').trigger("change");

        alert($('#selectCountry option:selected').val());


    });

          <select id="selectCountry" name="personal[country]"> 
    <option value="">[Select]</option>                      
    <?php foreach($countryList as $cl):?>

    <option value="<?php echo $cl['id'] ?>"
           for ="<?php echo $cl['internet'] ?>" ><?php echo $cl['name'] ?></option>

    </select>
```